# Is the TFS CheckIn Policy Evaluate method being invoked on a static object

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have the following sample TFS CheckIn Policy:

```
[Serializable()]
public class AuditControlsPolicy : PolicyBase
{

    public List<string> list;

    public AuditControlsPolicy() : base()
    {
        list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("in constructor");
    }

    public override string Description
    {
        get { return "my description"; }
    }

    public override string Type
    {
        get { return "my policy"; }
    }

    public override string TypeDescription
    {
        get { return "description"; }
    }

    public override string InstallationInstructions
    {
        get { return "install instructions"; }
    }

    public override Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.PolicyFailure[] Evaluate()
    {

        List<PolicyFailure> policyFailures = new List<PolicyFailure>();

        if (list == null)
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("list is null");
        else
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(String.Join(",", list.ToArray()));

        return policyFailures.ToArray();
    }

    public override void DisplayHelp(PolicyFailure failure)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No help available at this time");
    }

    public override void Activate(PolicyFailure failure)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(failure.Message);
    }

    protected override void OnPolicyStateChanged(PolicyFailure[] failures)
    {
        base.OnPolicyStateChanged(failures);
    }

    public override void Initialize(IPendingCheckin pendingCheckin)
    {
        base.Initialize(pendingCheckin);
        pendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChangesChanged += PendingCheckinCheckedPendingChangesChanged;
    }

    public override void Dispose()
    {
        PendingCheckin.PendingChanges.CheckedPendingChangesChanged -= PendingCheckinCheckedPendingChangesChanged;
        base.Dispose();
    }

    private void PendingCheckinCheckedPendingChangesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnPolicyStateChanged(Evaluate());
    }

    public override bool Edit(IPolicyEditArgs policyEditArgs)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

It is properly registered and "works" -- however, it appears that the instance member field `list` is not initialized when the `Evaluate` method is called.

When I toggle to Pending Changes view in Visual Studio with at least one pending change I get the message box of "In Constructor" multiple times. This is followed by "list is null", even though I clearly initialize the field in my instance constructor. If I declare my `list` as a static and initialize it in the instance constructor, then it display my list of values.

It almost seems as if Visual Studio is invoking the `Evaluate` method on a static object, even though it is not declared as such.

Is the `Evaluate` method being invoked as a static? Am I missing something about how I should be constructing my Policy Object?

Answer (score 0):

Evaluate method shouldn't be invoked on a static class and the Visual Studio also will not invoke the Evaluate method on a static object. There must be something wrong in your code, try to move `list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };` to `public override void Initialize(IPendingCheckin pendingCheckin)` and try again.

According to your description and code, guess the Evaluate() method had being invoked on the parent class `PolicyBase` before `AuditControlsPolicy`, that's why you got the `list is nul`.

Comment: I am not displaying a MessageBox in my check-in policy. My sample code is an attempt to illustrate a problem I am seeing. The `PolicyBase` class is an instance class, as is my derived Checkin class. The `Evaluate` method is also in instance method. As you can see in the code, there is an instance variable named `list` which is initialized in the constructor for the class to 'a','b','c'. I would expect that when Evaluate it is invoked by Visual Studio, `list` would contain 'a','b','c', however it does not. It is null.

Comment: If I make `list` a static, then I get my 'a','b','c' values. It seems like Visual Studio is not invoking Evaluate on the instance of the object.

Comment: @codechurn Sorry for the misunderstanding, Evaluate method shouldn't be invoked on a static class
and  the Visual Studio  also will not invoke the Evaluate method on a static object. There must be something wrong in your code, try to move   `list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };` to `public override void Initialize(IPendingCheckin pendingCheckin)` and try again

Comment: I did move `list = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" }`  to `Initialize` and got the list output as expected (the values) when `Evaluate` was invoked. What I don't understand is *why* the `list` is not initialized in the constructor.

Comment: @codechurn Didn't noticed the comment. Sorry for the later reply. According to your description and my test, guess the Evaluate() method had being invoked on the parent class `PolicyBase` before `AuditControlsPolicy`, that's why you got the `list is nul`.

Comment: Even if the `Evaluate` method is being invoked in the base class first (which makes sense), the constructor of the derived class should fire before the invocation of the derived class's `Evaluate` method -- right? and the constructor is where the list is initialized.

Comment: @codechurn `the constructor of the derived class should fire before the invocation of the derived class's Evaluate method -- right?`  Actually NO, if so the error shouldn't be exist. It should be  Evaluate method in  base class→ .. → derived class → derived class's override Evaluate method  → back to derived class's constructor

Comment: @codechurn Any update on this issue, have it been solved? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?